# onUpdateNavigationState() error

Tags: android, navigation, skmaps

I am in the process of upgrading from Skobbler 2.3 to the latest 2.5 and I am picking up an error with navigation.

When onUpdateNavigationState() is called, all data in the SKNavigationState object is always empty. For instance, getCurrentAdviceDistanceToAdvice() is always 0, getCurrentAdviceCurrentStreetName() is always "" etc. The only value that is consistently populated is from getCurrentAdviceTimeToDestination(), but that value is always incorrect. The value should be in the region of 16 hours, but is more like 440 hours.

Other problems are:

- Visual advices are not displayed correctly
- Audio advices are not heard, both when using Text to speech and when using audio files

Interestingly, the route is calculated correctly. The map is displayed correctly, complete with road names etc. The map can be panned, zoomed etc correctly. When navigation is started, the calculated route is displayed correctly and when using the simulator, follower mode is activated correctly and the vehicle follows the calculated route. However the SKNavigationState object always contains empty values even though looking at the map, I can see the name of the road displayed.

I've checked SKMaps.zip and the correct language files are included etc.

Originally, I tried upgrading from 2.3 to 2.5. After this failed (i.e. with the problems above) I abandoned upgrading and now I am unzipping SKMaps.zip to a completely new location on disk, but the problem persists. No preloaded maps are being used.

The problem occurs even after uninstalling the app. I've tried installing on a completely different phone and the problem still remains.

None of these were issues with the 2.3 API which just worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Test phones:

- Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3
- Galaxy Note 4 running Android 5.0.1

Comment: Which language do you use for audio advices?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue several weeks ago, I found out that the paths where the Advisor files (audios, advices and other files) were wrong. I'd recommend you to debug the application where the AdvisorSettings files and paths are configured and double check whether those paths are well configured and the files inside them are properly located.

Regards.